# what are the differences of Core duo and Core 2 duo?

Tags: cache, intel-core2, dual-core

I know that Core Duo and Core 2 Duo both are dual core processors. I also know that Core 2 Duo can run at faster frequencies and is otherwise considered better than Core Duo.

But is there any difference between their cache memories? If yes, then what are those difference? For cache memories, I mean do they have same amount of l1 cache and l2 cache?

Apart from that is there any other architectural difference?

Comment: There are many differences, far to many to list, and yes how cache works was changed in the transistion to Core 2 Duo ( same basic arch of the Sandy/Ivy Bridge i3, i5, and i7 actually ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little searching yielded this nice article from anandtech:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/2056/4

This is just a snippet of the article comparing the two chips you ask about, there's lots more information in it. The page i link gives a side by side comparison of the processors specs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. I am searching for this kind of article for last one hour. thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's just a link off-site.